# ERROR 1064 in mysql query for creating table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Getting 1064 mysql error in this code....

```
CREATE TABLE User(
    user_id int(10), 
    first_name varchar2(30) NOT NULL, 
    last_name varchar2(30) NOT NULL, 
    user_name varchar2(20), 
    email_id varchar2(50), 
    password varchar2(20) NOT NULL, 
    contact_no varchar2(15), 
    highest_degree varchar2(30) NOT NULL, 
    photo longblob, 
    STATE varchar2(25), 
    score int NOT NULL, 
    institute_name varchar2(50), 
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id), 
    UNIQUE (user_name), 
    UNIQUE(email_id)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Can't figure out how to eliminate it.. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Have you try in sql or mysql?

Comment: @NullPoiиteя this is not a problem of using reserved words. it is problem of using non-existing data type

Comment: ahhhh `varchar2` is in oracle and `varchar` is for mysql ..... yet this question shows no research efforts so should be closed ..... btw link for datatype http://sqlines.com/mysql/datatypes/varchar

Comment: @NullPoiиteя Yeah correct, but marking to a wrong duplicate also doesn't help anyone.So could you please revert it back if you can

Comment: @krishna alright reverted my vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No varchar2 in mysql** use **varchar**

This works

```
create table User(
  user_id int(10),
  first_name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  last_name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  user_name varchar(20),
  email_id varchar(50),
  password varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  contact_no varchar(15),
  highest_degree varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  photo longblob,
  state varchar(25),
  score int NOT NULL,
  institute_name varchar(50),
  PRIMARY KEY(user_id),
  UNIQUE (user_name),
  UNIQUE(email_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```